# Pick color for website background when using blue light filter software

Tags: colors, color-picker

**I need to figure out the color that I see after applying blue filter in the screen in order to use that color as background for a website.**

The background color of my website is `#0062cc`. When using `flux`  (blue light filter software) this color gets darker. I want to use this new darker color as a background color for my website. I need to figure out which color is this.

**Here is what I tried:**

I tried the color picker of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but they ignore the blue filter and don't pick the color that I see when using the blue filter software. Instead, they pick the original color `#0062cc` that I'm using in the website.

I took a screenshot (pressing `PtrSc`) of the website after turning on `flux`. Then I turned off flux to pick the color of the screenshot, but the `print screen` also ignored the blue filter and also got `#0062cc`.

Note: to try different colors until I get the darker color is not an option because there are over 16 million RGB colors and even focusing in a small range of these color I would have to try thousands of colors.

Comment: Have the same question! A good bet would be to take a photo of the screen (using e.g. your phone) and then use a color picker on the resulting photo. Tedious, but should work

Comment: Although it is not the ideal way of doing thins, your solution work! It's not ideal because the light in the room may affect color when taking a photo of the screen

Comment: you should post it as the answer

Comment: Sure, you got it! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the same question! A good bet would be to take a photo of the screen (using e.g. your phone) and then use a color picker on the resulting photo. Tedious, but should work

I've used the [Adobe Capture](https://www.adobe.com/products/capture.html) app and it's worked really well:

[image]